# Do objects call their destructor when they are assigned to a new one?

Tags: c++, constructor, garbage-collection, destructor

specifically take this code

```
function myfunction(){
  vector<T> foo,bar;
  //..put some objects into foo via push_back
  for(int i =0;i<foo.size;i++)
    if(foo[i].hasCondition())
      bar.push_back(foo[i]);
  foo = vector<T>();
  //do other stuff
}
```

so are the objects not contained by foo or bar anymore destructed?if not what's the correct way to only destruct the objects in foo that are not pointed to by bar?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Although in this case `bar` contains *copies* of the objects, so you'll get a second call to the destructor when it's destroyed.

Comment: Temporary instances like used here `foo = vector<T>();` will be destructed after use, yes.

Comment: aren't copies seperate instances of objects?so wouldn't the destruct calls be on two distinct objects?

Comment: @user2268997 yes that's what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

The correct algorithm for your use case is `copy_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for copy_if
#include <functional>   // for mem_fn
#include <iterator>     // for make_move_iterator and back_inserter

auto it = std::make_move_iterator(foo.begin());
auto e = std::make_move_iterator(foo.end());

std::copy_if(it, e, std::back_inserter(bar), std::mem_fn(&T::hasCondition));

foo.clear();            // destroy what's left of them
```

(Wrapping the iterators in `make_move_iterator` allows you to move the elements efficiently rather than making copies and immediately destroying the originals. Consider it an explicit version of a non-existing `move_if` algorithm.)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store objects of type `T` by `std::shared_ptr` instead of store them by value:

```
function myfunction(){
  typedef std::shared_ptr<T> TPtr;
  vector<TPtr> foo,bar;
  //..put some objects into foo via push_back and make_shared
  for(int i =0;i<foo.size;i++)
    if(foo[i]->hasCondition())
      bar.push_back(foo[i]);
  foo = vector<T>();
  //do other stuff
}
```

In your code you will copy some of the objects from `foo` to `bar` based on `hasCondition()` and all objects in `foo` will be destroyed when you assign `foo = vector<T>()`